# Refreshing browser not loading page but works while navigating through menu links (Angular)

Tags: angular, angular-routing

The site works fine on local server, but after deploying to a remote server the page reload not loading component.
It works only when clicked to nav links.
The site is https://astrohimalaya.com/. Components created only for home and about. I can not refresh from about page.
Help needed

Comment: tell me if that doesn't solve your issue and I'll reopen it

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure URL Rewrites on your hosting. Basically anything that hits your domain needs to point back to the index.html and the frontend router will take care of the state/page to display.

---

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites